# Responsive shape-based layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a little design for a site that's comprised of the main content being in a square roughly 80% the width of the site, and then a header, footer and two sidebars being signalled via lines. I have the header, footer, lines and content all working, and they all (mostly) stay in the right place when resized. However, I can't for the life of me work out how to get the square in the center to continue to fill the section in the middle of the screen (without overlapping, or having a scroll bar!)

I've attached the code for my square and some screenshots of what I'm attempting to do and what currently happens below. Other than my innercontent div, there're no divs on the side, and a header and footer div above and below.

*Update: Added code as requested. I believe this is all that's used in the example I provided in the screenshots, other than the lines, which are produced via some JS. I've included the important css here too, so to allow me to link to my JS Fiddle with it all:

```css
/* ===================
    Inital Styles
   =================== */

html {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #3f51b5;
  line-height: 1.4;
  animation: fade 5s
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #6534ff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #3f51b5;
  text-shadow: none;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.browserupgrade {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}

body {
  font: 16px/26px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 3.1;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: justify;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-container {
  height: 145px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.subTitle {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

.innercontent {
  position: relative;
  height: 3vw;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 32.5vw;
  margin-top: -28px;
  margin-left: 10.0%;
}

.green {
  background: #42ab9e;
}


/* ===================
    Name Collection
   =================== */

#nameCollection {
  text-align: center;
}

#nameText {
  margin-top: -28%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nameSkipButton {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-size: 210% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #963019 50%, #16174f 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s;
  transition: background-position 0.3s;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nameSkipButton:hover {
  background-position: 99%, 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="delay">
    <div class="fade-in delay">
      <div class="header-container">
        <header class="header-center">
          <h1 class="title" onclick="location.reload();" style="cursor: pointer;">COMPUTERIFY.IO</h1>
          <p class="subTitle" onclick="location.reload();" style="cursor: pointer;">Alpha is just a fancy word for unfinished.</p>
          <p class="subTitle">
            </h1>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="main-container">
        <div id="content" class="innercontent green">
          <div id="nameCollection">
            <div id="nameText">
              <h3>Hello. I'm the PC Generator, or PCG for short. Before we get started, can I just ask...</h3>
              <h1>What's your first name?</h1>
              <div>
                <input type="button" style="display:none" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="getUserName()" />
                <span class="input input--nameCollection">
                      <input class="input__field input__field--nameCollection" maxlength="19" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" type="text" id="input-25" />
                      <label class="input__label input__label--nameCollection" for="input-25">
                        <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--nameCollection">First Name</span>
                </label>
                </span>
              </div>
              <input class="nameSkipButton" id="skipName" type="button" value="I don't value my name, pick one for me" onclick="confirmSkip();" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nxyg4a9x/2/

[Attached screenshots demonstrating the design when it works (on a 1920x1080 display, and how it looks on resize and on mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1QSD.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
FWIW, using absolute positioning for page layout is a poor choice if you want your site to be responsive. Elements are not able to properly react to one another when the viewport size changes.

Comment: Apologies, I can make a jsfiddle now if you'd like? What would you recommend I use to position my divs instead, to make them more responsive?

Comment: Create a Stack Snippet if you can. Recommendations will follow.

Comment: To clarify hungerstar's comment -> Stack Snippets are handy little code blocks you can insert in your question that are runnable directly on the page.  It's in the toolbar when you're editing your question.  Alternatively JSFiddle (as you said) or CodePen (my preference) are good ways to share your code.

Comment: Sorry. Hopefully that's what you wanted. If not, I'll make a codepen with the entire site (though, it's quite big, and this is just a small snippet!)

Comment: @JoshCawthorne that's pretty good. I might add a background color like you have in your screenshot so we can see some of the text and even your lines. You mention you used JS to create them but I'm not seeing why you wouldn't be able to do it with CSS instead (preferred).

Comment: Just spent ages trying to add it all into the editor and it wasn't having it, so I've put it all on jsfiddle. That should be near identical now, bar a few minor visual styles. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: I've added your jsfiddle as a Stack Snippet. Some users view Stack Overflow from work, where they are blocked from code-sharing sites like jsfiddle. Using Stack Snippets allow those users to collaborate.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that, but it makes sense. I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [**`flexbox`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) if you can.

The following is a demo and you'll likely need to make adjustments to fit your needs.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  margin: 0 10%; // Indirect way of making element width: 80%;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 2px solid lightgray;
}

header,
footer {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #42ab9e;
}

main:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: -100%;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -100%;
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

- The most important thing that we did is use `flex-grow: 1` on `main` which addresses your primary concern of stretching your content area to fill the appropriate space. `flex-grow: 1` tells the element to take up any remaining space inside of it's parent element. So whatever space is left over from the height of the `header` and `footer` it will file up.
- We use `min-height` on `body` as a starting point so that `main` doesn't end up a fixed size (which is what would have happened if we used `height` instead) and the layout fills the viewport initially even if there is not a lot of content.
- You mentioned using JS to create your lines, that seems like overkill to me and can be accomplished with CSS. The lines are just borders and the only non obvious set of lines would be the horizontal lines that extend outside of `main`. I did this with a pseudo element that stretches itself outside of it's parent element. The top and bottom of the pseudo element are pulled outside of it's containing element equal to the border's thickness. The left and right of the pseudo element are pulled out just wide enough to always extend a little past the viewport window (I used a relative unit so it will grow with the viewport). We used `overflow: hidden;` on `body` to prevent a horizontal scrollbar that this element initially creates.

Hope this works for you and let me know if you have any questions, cheers!

Comment: Hi. Apologies for a delay in response. I've spent a few hours re-writing my site to implement the above code that you provided me with and it works great until it comes down to the lines. I appreciate that you said it'd work better with CSS, and you're right, it does. But, I've been using a JS plugin to animate my lines. This means that the lines stay in exact position, even when the content doesn't. Is there any way to sort this, or do I have to lose the animation?

I've uploaded my code to a git and there's a link to live version there. 
[Github](https://github.com/joshcawthorne/pcify.io)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.innercontent` div, you are using the `vw` measurement which stands for "viewport width" - basically what this means is that the height of your box is going to be relative to the width of the screen/viewport that the user is viewing the site in.

You need to set height, width margin etc in another unit other than `vw` since it will result in what you're seeing. I forked your fiddle to demonstrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/550n5wgn/1/

Comment: I've edited my code to now use "height: 80%;", however the same problem still occurs and it doesn't continue to fill 80% of the screen when resized?

Comment: Is the "computerify.io" supposed to be in the green or outside of it? If inside, you would need to put those headers in the div that is the green box.

Comment: It should be outside. If you look at the imgur link, you can see the lines which I've left out of the jsfiddle, but it's basically the menu/header.

Comment: @kawnah content still overflows the parent (green box).